# How to convert an array of hashes into XML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have an array of database objects, `@configs`, that I want to convert to the XML format but the output is not the expected. Every entry gets enclosed in a `<map>` tag instead of a `<entry>` tag, I only wanted `<tag>` to be the XML root. How do I build the XML with the `<tag>` root and put all the entries in a `<entry>` tag?
Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Here is my code:

```
    entries = Array.new
    entry = Hash.new
    conf = Hash.new  

    @configs.each do |config|

      entry.store('string', config.key)

      conf.store('value', config.value)
      conf.store('comment', config.comment)

      entry.store('com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty', conf)

      entries << entry    

    end

    pp entries.to_xml(:root => 'map', :indent => 0, :skip_types => true)
```

And the result is:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<map>
    <map>
        <string>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER_CHANNEL</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER</value>
            <comment>Canal que irÃ¡ receber tudo o que for logged com Warning e Error</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </map>
    <map>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_ACCESS_CONTROL</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/pnbAccessControl.json</value>
            <comment>Este ficheiro permite configurar AutenticaÃ§Ã£o e Controlo de Acessos.</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </map>
    <map>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_CONNECTION_POOLS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/pnbConnectionPools.json</value>
            <comment>ConfiguraÃ§Ã£o de Oracle Universal Connection Pools usadas pelo PNB (PEM, RCU2)</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </map>
    <map>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_CSP_MC_EXCLUSIONS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/medCronExclusions/mcExclCurrentRevision.json</value>
            <comment>N/A</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </map>
    <map>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_FACILITIES_ALIAS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/snsFacilitiesAlias.json</value>
            <comment>Mapa de alias do codigo das instituicoes do SNS.</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </map>
</map>
```

What I wanted:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<map>
    <entry>
        <string>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER_CHANNEL</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER</value>
            <comment>Canal que irÃ¡ receber tudo o que for logged com Warning e Error</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_ACCESS_CONTROL</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/pnbAccessControl.json</value>
            <comment>Este ficheiro permite configurar AutenticaÃ§Ã£o e Controlo de Acessos.</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_CONNECTION_POOLS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/pnbConnectionPools.json</value>
            <comment>ConfiguraÃ§Ã£o de Oracle Universal Connection Pools usadas pelo PNB (PEM, RCU2)</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_CSP_MC_EXCLUSIONS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/medCronExclusions/mcExclCurrentRevision.json</value>
            <comment>N/A</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_FACILITIES_ALIAS</string>
        <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
            <value>resources/configPnbDev/snsFacilitiesAlias.json</value>
            <comment>entrya de alias do codigo das instituicoes do SNS.</comment>
        </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
    </entry>
</map>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
    pp entries.to_xml(:root => 'map', :children => 'entry', :indent => 0, :skip_types => true)
```

source: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_xml

Answer (score 1):

Suppose entry is the following hash:

```
entry = {
  a: “hello”,
  b: “goodbye”,
}
```

If you write:

```
entries = []
entries << entry
p entries
```

then the output is:

```
[{:a => “hello”, {:b => “goodbye”}]
```

So if you then write:

```
p entries.to_xml
```

how do you suppose the word “entry” will ever appear in the output?  That's sort of like expecting the output of:

```
x = 10
y = 20
puts x+y
```

to include the letters "x" and "y" somewhere.

According to the to_xml() docs for arrays:

> Returns a string ... by invoking to_xml on each element.
>   The options hash is passed downwards.
>   http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_xml

The fact that the options hash is passed downwards means that when you specify `{root: map}` for the to_xml() call on the array, then `<map>` will become the root of the xml, and when `to_xml()` is called on each array element the method will be called with the option `{root: “map”}`, which will cause each array element to be wrapped in a `<map>` tag.  For instance:

```
puts [{a: 10, b: 20}, {a: 100, b: 200}].to_xml({root: "map"})

--output:--

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map type="array">
  <map>
    <a type="integer">10</a>
    <b type="integer">20</b>
  </map>
  <map>
    <a type="integer">100</a>
    <b type="integer">200</b>
  </map>
</map>
```

The nested `<map>` tags are a side effect of a feature built into the to_xml() method: if you specify a plural name for the :root option when calling to_xml() on an array, e.g. “maps”, then when rails turns around and calls to_xml() on each element of the array, rails will specify the singular “map” for the :root option. That makes some sense because if you call to_xml() on an array and you specify the :root option to be “maps” then naturally each array element would probably be a "map".  Of course, that isn’t what you want.

Luckily, as mr_sudaca pointed out, there is this:

> By default name of the node for the children of root is
>   root.singularize. You can change it with the `:children option`.
>   http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_xml

As a result, this code:

```
require 'ostruct'

configs = [
  OpenStruct.new(
    key: "PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER_CHANNEL",
    value: "PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER",
    comment: "Canal que...",
  ),
  OpenStruct.new(
    key: "PNB_CFG_FILE_ACCESS_CONTROL",
    value: "resources/configPnbDev/pnbAccessControl.json",
    comment: "Este ficheiro...",
  )
]

entries = []

configs.each do |config|
  entry = {}
  conf = {}

  entry.store('string', config.key)

  conf.store('value', config.value)
  conf.store('comment', config.comment)

  entry.store('com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty', conf)

  entries << entry
end

p entries
puts entries.to_xml(:root => 'map', children: "entry", :skip_types => true)
```

produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
  <entry>
    <string>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER_CHANNEL</string>
    <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
      <value>PNB_ALERTLOG_RECEIVER</value>
      <comment>Canal que...</comment>
    </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>PNB_CFG_FILE_ACCESS_CONTROL</string>
    <com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
      <value>resources/configPnbDev/pnbAccessControl.json</value>
      <comment>Este ficheiro...</comment>
    </com.mirth.connect.util.ConfigurationProperty>
  </entry>
</map>
```

It looks to me like you also have some problems with your entry and conf hashes as every element in the entries array will refer to the same entry and conf hash, and because your loop keeps changing those hashes, each entry in the array will refer to a hash that contains the last key/values set in the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment and detailed explanation @7stud, it really helped me understand to_xml(). Thanks for your time!